# Faced Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: reactjs

I was using an alternative version of classNames package in React project. So, I have this code:

```
className={concatClasses({[classes.dialogActions]: isNewDataSource})}
```

which shows error of **Argument of type '{ [x: string]: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.**

Comment: what is the value of classes.dialogActions ?

Comment: @Max, it is string

Comment: it seems a problem with concatClasses and that param: what function is?